# Excel autofilter range: keep the range unchanged / avoid that rows are added automatically

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, autofilter

I have an issue to limit the Excel autofilter to the set range and display a sticky bottom row below that range...

This works well (I am using Python xlsxwriter):

```
worksheet.autofilter('A1:D111')
```

It results in a filter list range in Excel (Office 365) of $A$1:$D$111.

However, if I write a cell below the autofilter range with:

```
worksheet.write(111, 3, 'Total filtered selection', format_string) #adds string to Excel row 112
```

Then this row is also included in the filterrange (the filter now ends at $D112 for some reason... see picture).

Due to this the bottom row is not sticking to the bottom of the selection on changing the filter, which is what I wanted in order to show a total for the selection (using `=SUBTOTAL(101, E1:E111)` which only includes filtered rows as intended).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just the standard behaviour of Excel, that it "helpfully" extends out filter ranges to include data added below the origin filter? You could verify it by creating a similar example in Excel.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the same happens when doing this manually in Excel. It is probably a bad idea to put a manual total at the bottom like this. I will go for a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By using the same range for a chart series the autofilter range remains unchanged:**

As dwirony suggested, it seems to be standard behavior for Excel to add new data (rows) to the autofilter. This way the filter range is extended with my bottom row showing subtotals and the row is hidden when the filter is reapplied.

However, if you apply a chart series to the same range of cells as the autofilter range then the autofilter remains unchanged! I.e. my autofilter range was 'A1:D111' and changed to 'A1:D112' on adding content to row 112. However, if I create a chart series for range 'A1:D111' and add content to row 112 then the autofilter range will remain unchanged.

*PS note: I also tried to keep the range fixed by defining a named range (without using it) but this does not help / the filter still adds new rows outside the named range automatically. In xlsx writer:*

```
workbook.define_name('Filterrange', '={}!$A$1:$D$111'
```